# how do I return back after catching an error?

Tags: c#, for-loop, iteration

```
for (int loopCount = 0; loopCount < 9; loopCount++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee #" + (loopCount + 1) + " first name: ");
    fullName[loopCount, 0] = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    // first name
    if (fullName[loopCount, 0].Length == 0)
    {
        giveError();
        // nothing typed warning               
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Employee #" + (loopCount + 1) + " second name: ");
    fullName[0, loopCount] = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    // second name
}
```

How do I return back to adding a first name if the user enters nothing without moving on to the next loop?

Comment: I'm pretty new, sorry in advance for lack of explanation.

Comment: i'm confused - its up to you what you want to return.

Comment: I've tried `continue` but it then continues to the next loop `[0 ,0]` to `[1, 0]`

Comment: @nqt, when you don't want to continue a loop's execution you can use a `break;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing your loop structure, you can add the following lines after `giveError();` inside you `if` statment:

```
loopcount--;
continue;
```

This will decrement your `loopcount`, so you do not loose your place and will return your program to the top of the loop and then re-increment loopcount.

Comment: works perfectly! How did I miss something so simple :/

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your logic around a do while loop:

```
string name = null;

do
{
  // Read input from user

}
while(!IsLegal(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an empty value before you ask for input, and then wrap the input code in a while loop that continues asking until a valid value is given:

```
string fullname = string.Empty;
while(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullname))
{
    fullname = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
fullName[loopCount, 0] = fullname;
```

This way, if the user doesn't type anything, you'll just loop back and ask again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming fullName is a `string[9,2]`:

```
for (int loopCount = 0; loopCount < 9; loopCount++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Employee #" + (loopCount + 1) + " first name: ");

   fullName[loopCount, 0] = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
   while(fullName[loopCount, 0].Length == 0)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Bad Input, Retry");
       fullName[loopCount, 0] = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
   }
}
```

It's worth the extra input line before the loop, so that if the loop is needed (i.e. bad input is received) you can supply a "bad input" message.

for your second name, you want `fullName[loopCount,1]`, not `fullName[0,loopCount]`